# How do I design the following using pure CSS and HTML and Bootstrap (with check icon)?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to design the following design using pure CSS, HTML and Bootstrap.
[image]

The content inside the green circle is supposed to be a check mark sign (I couldn't achieve it in Paint though)

Also note the text inside the large circle.I want it to be exactly in the center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #CCCCCC;
  display: flex;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

.circle:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -10px;
  border: 5px solid #FFF;
}

.circle:after {
  content: '✔';
  position: absolute;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  bottom: 13px;
  left: 6px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <span>Name</span>
  <span>54</span>
  <span>some text</span>
</div>
```

[Check out the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n1fhe4Lj/)

Comment: For reference, see [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Pseudo-classes_and_pseudo-elements#Pseudo-elements) like [::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) and [::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after).